# Sql executa no Oracle SQL Developer, mas não executa na aplicação C#

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-insert

```
vsql = @"INSERT INTO ALUNOS_ (UF, IDADE, TELEFONE, NOME_PAI, ENDERECO, EMAIL, 
                             NOME, CIDADE, NOME_MAE)
        values ('sp', 0,'','','','','','','');";
```

Esta SQL quando executada no oracle faz a inserção mas na aplicação da o erro

> ORA-00933: comando SQL não encerrado adequadamente;

O que pode ser?

Resolvido apenas tirando o ponto e virgula no fim da sql.

Outra duvida que surgiu agora com parametros, [Sql executa no Oracle SQL Developer, mas não executa na aplicação C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273156/sql-executa-no-oracle-sql-developer-mas-n%C3%A3o-executa-na-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É bem simples na verdade

Seu sql:

```
vsql = @"INSERT INTO ALUNOS_ (UF, IDADE, TELEFONE, NOME_PAI, ENDERECO, EMAIL, 
                             NOME, CIDADE, NOME_MAE)
        values ('sp', 0,'','','','','','','');";
```

Sql funcional;

```
vsql = @"INSERT INTO ALUNOS_ (UF, IDADE, TELEFONE, NOME_PAI, ENDERECO, EMAIL, 
                             NOME, CIDADE, NOME_MAE)
        values ('sp', 0,'','','','','','','')";
```

Você pode verificar que removi somente um ponto e virgula da sua string, pois isso ele não consegue interpretar.

Comment: KKK Cara estou a dois dias nisso, valeu mesmo. Mas um outro problema persiste, vou colocar aqui.

Comment: @BrunoVinicius Se for diferente marque essa como resolvida e crie outra pergunta

Comment: Sou novo aqui, como faço para marcar como resolvido?

Comment: Ja marcou é só setar o viès